# Does anyone know a free render farm that allows drivers?

Tags: rendering, drivers

After I finally (thanks to Mr. Zak) got all my linked objects into a packed file, I discovered that I have been using drivers to pose the proxies of my charcters in the scene - sorry, I have been working with blender for only 2 weeks now and am tackling problems as they come. the render frarm SheepIt! shuts off the drivers, so all my characters do not render correctly. I understand the reaseon for shuting off the drivers, but what can I do now? Do I have to redo the whole scene without proxies - appending instead of linking and losing the advantages of the linking?  or does anyone know a free render farm that allows drivers? ... many thanks!!!

Comment: You could ask https://render.st/artists/

Comment: they are a real good option for a later date - when I really have a movie :-) ... I am just starting to get to know blender and its numerous posibilities ... and doing a lot of test rendering ... thank you anyways, it´s a good tip :-)